# Как инициировать событие при изменении переменной, в которую записано исключение?

Tags: python, pyqt5, логирование, sqlalchemy

Исключения, которые появляются в процессе работы программы сейчас пишутся в текстбокс окна, мне нужно, чтобы при включенном чекбоксе (log_in_DB) они писались сразу и в таблицу бд (функция log_in_sql_server, подключение к бд работает). Я пытаюсь сейчас сделать это через слоты и сигналы.

1. источник события - изменение self.msg в классе QTextEditLogger
2. слот это функция log_in_sql_server в классе MainWindow

```
class QTextEditLogger(logging.Handler):
    valueChanged = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__()
        self.widget = parent.ui.plainTextEdit
        self.widget.setReadOnly(True)

    def emit(self, record):
        self.msg = self.format(record)
        self.widget.appendPlainText(self.msg)

    @property
    def msg(self):
        return self._msg

    @msg.setter
    def msg(self, value):
        self._msg = value
        self.valueChanged.emit(value)


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

        self.log_text_box = QTextEditLogger(self)
        self.log_text_box.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s  %(module)s.%(funcName)s((lineno)d)  
                                                               %(levelname)s:%(message)s'))
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(self.log_text_box)
        logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        self.ui.plainTextEdit.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextSelectableByMouse)

        self.log_text_box.valueChanged.connect(self.log_in_sql_server)

    def initUI(self):
        self.ui.log_in_DB.clicked.connect(self.log_in_sql_server)

    def log_in_sql_server(self, msg):
        try:
            if self.ui.log_in_DB.isChecked():
                Session = db.sessionmaker()
                session = Session(bind=db.engine)
                new_post = db.UserException(message="сообщение из форматтера", 
                                            target_site="место где произошло исключение",
                                            date_time_exc='аскитайм из форматтера', 
                                            index_form=1)
                session.add(new_post)
                session.commit()
        except ValueError as e:
            logging.debug(e, exc_info=True)
```

Эта реализация дает ошибку: QTextEditLogger cannot be converted to PyQt5.QtCore.QObject in this context.

И еще, как после передачи self.msg разбить ее на нужные мне части? может есть что-то встроенное, потому что разбивать строку на строки между пробелами звучит не слишком хорошо.

Comment: Насчет self.msg - приведите пример значения, находящегося в данной переменной

Comment: полноценно сформированное исключение. Вот что выводит print(self.msg): C:\Users\a_vik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe "C:/Users/a_vik/Documents/учеба/4 курс/7 семестр/РИС/full_project/main.py"
2020-11-19 23:02:51,302  main.open_file(72)  DEBUG:[Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/a_vik/Documents/учеба/4 курс/7 семестр/РИС/full_project/main.py", line 68, in open_file
    file = open(file_name, 'r', encoding="utf8")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: ''

Comment: Насчет разбиения - я бы задал отдельный вопрос, в котором бы указал как именно надо разбить строку

Answer (score 0):

Класс, использующий сигналы-слоты должен быть наследником QObject. Надо немного переделать:

```py
import logging

class LoggingHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self, textLogger):
        super().__init__()
        self._textLogger = textLogger

    @property
    def msg(self):
        return self._msg

    @msg.setter
    def msg(self, value):
        self._msg = value
        self._textLogger.valueChanged.emit(value)

class QTextEditLogger(QObject):
    valueChanged = Signal(str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.handler = LoggingHandler(textLogger=self)

    def emit(self, record):
        self.handler.msg = self.handler.format(record)
        self.widget.appendPlainText(self.msg)
```

Теперь в окне:

```py
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

        self.log_text_box = QTextEditLogger(self)
        ...
        logging.getLogger().addHandler(self.log_text_box.handler)
```

Comment: Если просто вставить ваш код в мой, то не работает и вот такая ошибка - NameError: name 'QTextEditLogger' is not defined. Класс LogginHandler не понимает что такое QTextEditLogger

Comment: @a_vikt вы можете LogginHandler(logging.Handler) определить внутри QTextEditLogger

Comment: точно так же ругается даже после изменения

Comment: @a_vikt немного вернул назад (чуть исправил) и проверил - все работает и не ругается